# How to get a list of files created after certain time?

Tags: python

Currently, I can get the stats on the files within a dir. What would be an efficient way to just get a list of files created after 6:00 PM?

```
for r, d, f in os.walk(dir):
    for file in f:
        print(file)
        print(os.path.join(r, file))
        print(os.path.getctime(os.path.join(r, file)))
        print(os.stat(os.path.join(r, file)))
```

Comment: You probably want mtime, not ctime. ctime is "change" time (when metadata, like permissions or ownership was last changed), not creation time. Most UNIX filesystems don't track creation time at all, so modification time is the closest thing you have.

Comment: Not related to question: save `os.path.join(r, file)` in a  variable and use that when printing, instead of calling the function (and thus repeating the operation) 3 times.

Comment: If you know nothing of the files, this is the most efficient. If another of your program creates them, then create a database containig the creation time and file name, than you can efficiently query for files created in an interval.